# Is it permissible to kill a lizard and other animals of it's species like chameleon, salamander etc?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, islamic-philosophy, authenticity

I want to know that can I kill a lizard, chameleon or a salamander even if they are not hurting me?

I have heard of some hadith in which it is mentioned that killing them is an act of worship and it is considered as a good deed. Is this an authentic hadith? How can killing Allah's creation for no reason be a good deed?

Comment: [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50705/hadith-or-verses-saying-killing-a-lizard-is-a-reward) is somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Animals that islam allowed to kill it.

rats and mice, scorpions, crows(black and white), kites and wild dogs."

> حَدَّثَنِي عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ هِشَامِ بْنِ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ،
>   أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ خَمْسٌ فَوَاسِقُ
>   يُقْتَلْنَ فِي الْحَرَمِ الْفَأْرَةُ وَالْعَقْرَبُ وَالْغُرَابُ
>   وَالْحِدَأَةُ وَالْكَلْبُ الْعَقُورُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Yahya related to me from Malik from Hisham ibn Urwa from his father
>   that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace,
>   said, "There are five trespassers that can be killed in the Haram:
>   rats and mice, scorpions, crows, kites and wild dogs."

another Hadith

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) commanded to kill five harmful things in
>   the state of lhram or otherwise. The rest of the hadith is the same.

[here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/76)

```
In another hadith Gecko is allowed to kill it
```

> عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏:‏
>   “من قتل وزغة في أول ضربة فله كذا وكذا حسنة،ومن قتلها في الضربة
>   الثانية، فله كذا وكذا حسنة، ودون الأول وإن قتلها في الضربة الثالثة،
>   فله كذا وكذا حسنة” ‏(‏‏(‏رواه مسلم‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏ وفي رواية‏:‏ ‏ "‏من قتل
>   وزغاً في أول ضربة، كتب له مائة حسنة، وفى الثانية دون ذلك، وفى الثالثة
>   دون ذلك‏"‏

Another narration is: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "If anyone kills a Gecko with the first blow, a hundred good deeds will be recorded for him; less than that will be recorded for him if he kills it at the second blow, and still less rewards will be recorded for him if he kills it at the third blow."

there are condition when you kill it you should not just search for it to kill it 
and for snake in home: that is because of the possibility that it may be a jinn. [here](https://islamqa.info/en/244237)

> قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ إِنَّ لِهَذِهِ الْبُيُوتِ
>   عَوَامِرَ فَإِذَا رَأَيْتُمْ شَيْئًا مِنْهَا فَحَرِّجُوا عَلَيْهَا
>   ثَلاَثًا فَإِنْ ذَهَبَ وَإِلاَّ فَاقْتُلُوهُ فَإِنَّهُ كَافِرٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>   وَقَالَ لَهُمُ ‏"‏ اذْهَبُوا فَادْفِنُوا صَاحِبَكُمْ ‏"‏
>
> We visited Abu Sa'id Khudri. When we had been sitting (with him) we
>   heard a stir under his bed. When we looked we found a big snake, the
>   rest of the hadith is the same. And in this Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) is
>   reported to have said: Verily in these houses there live aged
>   (snakes), so when you see one of them, make life hard for it for three
>   days, and if it goes away (well and good), otherwise kill it for (in
>   that case) it would be a nonbeliever. And he (the Holy Prophet) said
>   (to his Companions): Go and bury your companion (who had died by the
>   snake bite).

```
 عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه و سلم قَالَ: 

"إنَّ اللَّهَ كَتَبَ الْإِحْسَانَ عَلَى كُلِّ شَيْءٍ، فَإِذَا قَتَلْتُمْ فَأَحْسِنُوا الْقِتْلَةَ، وَإِذَا ذَبَحْتُمْ فَأَحْسِنُوا الذِّبْحَ، 
وَلْيُحِدَّ أَحَدُكُمْ شَفْرَتَهُ، وَلْيُرِحْ ذَبِيحَتَهُ".
```

> Verily Allah has prescribed ihsan (proficiency, perfection) in all
>   things. So if you kill then kill well; and if you slaughter, then
>   slaughter well. Let each one of you sharpen his blade and let him
>   spare suffering to the animal he slaughters.”

```
I will not go in detail about another animals but behind
each one there is a reason we know it or we don't 
this is the reason why you should kill Gecko
```

> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا يُونُسُ بْنُ
>   مُحَمَّدٍ، عَنْ جَرِيرِ بْنِ حَازِمٍ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، عَنْ سَائِبَةَ، -
>   مَوْلاَةِ الْفَاكِهِ بْنِ الْمُغِيرَةِ - أَنَّهَا دَخَلَتْ عَلَى
>   عَائِشَةَ فَرَأَتْ فِي بَيْتِهَا رُمْحًا مَوْضُوعًا فَقَالَتْ يَا
>   أُمَّ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ مَا تَصْنَعِينَ بِهَذَا قَالَتْ نَقْتُلُ بِهِ
>   هَذِهِ الأَوْزَاغَ فَإِنَّ نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ
>   أَخْبَرَنَا أَنَّ إِبْرَاهِيمَ لَمَّا أُلْقِيَ فِي النَّارِ لَمْ
>   تَكُنْ فِي الأَرْضِ دَابَّةٌ إِلاَّ أَطْفَأَتِ النَّارَ غَيْرَ
>   الْوَزَغِ فَإِنَّهَا كَانَتْ تَنْفُخُ عَلَيْهِ فَأَمَرَ رَسُولُ
>   اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ بِقَتْلِهِ
>
> It was narrated from Sa’ibah, the freed slave woman of Fakih bin
>   Mughirah, that she entered upon ‘Aishah and saw a spear in her house.
>   She said: “O Mother of the Believers, what do you do with this?” She
>   said: “We kill these house lizards with it, for the Prophet of Allah
>   (ﷺ) told us that when Ibrahim was thrown into the fire, there was no
>   beast on earth that did not try to put it out, apart from the house
>   lizard that blew on it. So the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) commanded that
>   they should be killed.